# Image Name as variables(Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, variables, func

I am trying to call a func as below, what should I write in the loadImage() so that I can type in different image name whenever I call it.

Many Thanks

```
func loadImage(????){

        self.Picture.image = UIImage (named: "Ch1-4 new.jpg")

              UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0,
                                   delay: 0.0,
                                   options: [],
                                   animations : {

                                    let message = "Picture.mp3"
                                    let triggerTime = (Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 1)
                                    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, triggerTime), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                                        self.playMessageOpening(message)
                                    })
                                    self.Picture.hidden=false
                                    self.Picture.alpha=0.0;
                                    self.Picture.alpha=1.0;

            },
                                   completion: { finished in
                                    print("Picutre done")


        })
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func loadImage(imageName: String) {
    self.Picture.image = UIImage (named: imageName)

    ...
}
```

Where `imageName` is the name of the parameter and `String` is the type. More on function declarations in [the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).